# Custom JS to filter/switch between data frames using a Radio Group Button in a stand alone html document from bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, callback, pandas-groupby, bokeh

This is the first time I have posted here so sorry if the format is not correct, I am also fairly new to Python so still learning the ropes.

I have been using bokeh to build visualization tools for my work colleagues, I collect the data, run the script and then place the html on a server for everyone to access. It's been working great but i want to add a little more functionality to the bokeh plot other than the standard tools.

I have added a Radio Group button above the bokeh plot and I would like to use Custom JS code to either filter the data frame or switch between partial data frames that have already been filtered. I don't want to use the bokeh server as I don't want other people to have to do that, I just want them to open an html.

As you can see here:

```
# df_final is the main data frame

# this creates 3 data frames which i could switch between:

mask_sector_1 = (df_final['Lap Distance'] < 2000)
df_sector_1 = df_final[mask_sector_1]

mask_sector_2 = (df_final['Lap Distance'] > 2000) & (df_final['Lap Distance'] < 4000)
df_sector_2 = df_final[mask_sector_2]

mask_sector_3 = (df_final['Lap Distance'] > 4000) & (df_final['Lap Distance'] < 6000)
df_sector_3 = df_final[mask_sector_3]

# this adds a new column to the data frame which corresponds to the radio group button active value, to help with filtering:

df_final.loc[(df_final['Lap Distance'] < 2000), 'callback_tag'] = '0'
df_final.loc[(df_final['Lap Distance'] >= 2000) & (df_final['Lap Distance'] < 4000), 'callback_tag'] = '1'
df_final.loc[(df_final['Lap Distance'] >= 4000) & (df_final['Lap Distance'] < lap_distance_min), 'callback_tag'] = '2'
```

As you can see from the code below, I have no idea how to construct the JS code, despite looking at quite a few examples I cannot find something similar.

The other issue I have is that I am using a .groupby to make the plotting easier, but I am not sure how and where to implement the x, y and source = source variables when using column data source. I tried to do this but it failed every time.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import BoxAnnotation, Span, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider, LinearAxis, Range1d, Label, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox
from bokeh.io import output_notebook # , show
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
import itertools

# turn data frames into ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnataSource(df_final)
source1 = ColumnDataSource(df_sector_1)
source2 = ColumnDataSource(df_sector_2)
source3 = ColumnDataSource(df_sector_3)


# output to static HTML file
output_file("Mutli_driver.html")

# adding the interactive tools
tools = ["hover", "reset", "pan", "wheel_zoom", "box_zoom", 'save']

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p3 = figure(title = 'Driver_compare - All ' + str(n_fastest_laps) + ' Fastest Laps', x_axis_label='Lap Distance (m)', y_axis_label='variable',plot_width=1400, plot_height=650, tools=tools,x_range=(-810, lap_distance_min+100))
p3.background_fill_color = "whitesmoke"

# plot labels
RA_pow = Label(x = -750, y = -175, text = 'RA Lat Sliding Power', text_font_size = '10pt')
FA_pow = Label(x = -750, y = -100, text = 'FA Lat Sliding Power', text_font_size = '10pt')
CB = Label(x = -750, y = 0, text = 'Car Balance (^ = US)', text_font_size = '10pt')
curv = Label(x = -750, y = 300, text = 'Curvature', text_font_size = '10pt')

p3.add_layout(RA_pow)
p3.add_layout(FA_pow)
p3.add_layout(CB)
p3.add_layout(curv)

# Sector lines
vline = Span(location=2000, dimension='height', line_color='black', line_width=2, line_dash = 'dashed')
vline2 = Span(location=4000, dimension='height', line_color='black', line_width=2, line_dash = 'dashed')

p3.renderers.extend([vline, vline2])
    # p.add_layout(vline)


for [driver_label, trace_colour, lap_time_label, lap_number_label], group_compare in df_final.groupby(['driver','trace_colour', 'lap_time', 'lap_number']):


    CB_raw = group_compare['Car Balance']
    CB_smoothed = gaussian_filter1d(CB_raw, sigma=5)

    FA_pow_raw = group_compare['FA Lat Tyre Power']
    FA_pow_smoothed = gaussian_filter1d(FA_pow_raw, sigma=5)

    RA_pow_raw = group_compare['RA Lat Tyre Power']
    RA_pow_smoothed = gaussian_filter1d(RA_pow_raw, sigma=5)

    # not sure here where how to add x and y of the Column data source, and source = source
    p3.line(group_compare['Lap Distance'], group_compare['curvature']*2000+300, legend_label = driver_label + ' Lap - ' + str(lap_number_label) + ' = ' + str(round(lap_time_label, 2)), line_width = 1,line_color = trace_colour)



p3.legend.click_policy="hide"


codes = """

var f = cb_obj.active;

var sdata = source.data;
var data1 = source1.data;
var data2 = source2.data;

console.log(data2);

for (key in data1) {console.log(key);}

if (f == "0") {

# either use df_sector_1 or filter df_final for all values of df['callback_tag'] == 0


source.trigger("change");
"""

# add callback to control 
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p3, source=source,source1=source1,source2=source2), code=codes)

button = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["Sector_1", "Sector_2", "Sector_3"], active=0, callback = callback)

p3 = column(widgetbox(button), p3)

show(p3)
```

any help or guidance would be much appreciated, or let me know if i need to explain more or better

thanks

UPDATE: I have not got the customJS code working by basically filtering the original dataframe:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import BoxAnnotation, Span

from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider

from bokeh.io import output_notebook # , show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, Label

from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
import itertools

from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, RadioButtonGroup

#source = ColumnDataSource(df_final)

group = df_final.groupby(['driver','trace_colour', 'lap_time', 'lap_number'])
source = ColumnDataSource(group)


# adding the interactive tools
tools = ["hover", "reset", "pan", "wheel_zoom", "box_zoom", 'save']

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p3 = figure(title = 'Driver_compare - All ' + str(n_fastest_laps) + ' Fastest Laps', x_axis_label='Lap Distance (m)', y_axis_label='variable',plot_width=700, plot_height=500, tools=tools) # x_range=(-810, lap_distance_min+100)
p3.background_fill_color = "whitesmoke"


RA_pow = Label(x = -750, y = -175, text = 'RA Lat Sliding Power', text_font_size = '10pt')
FA_pow = Label(x = -750, y = -100, text = 'FA Lat Sliding Power', text_font_size = '10pt')
CB = Label(x = -750, y = 0, text = 'Car Balance (^ = US)', text_font_size = '10pt')
curv = Label(x = -750, y = 300, text = 'Curvature', text_font_size = '10pt')

p3.add_layout(RA_pow)
p3.add_layout(FA_pow)
p3.add_layout(CB)
p3.add_layout(curv)

# Sector lines
vline = Span(location=2000, dimension='height', line_color='black', line_width=2, line_dash = 'dashed')
vline2 = Span(location=4000, dimension='height', line_color='black', line_width=2, line_dash = 'dashed')

p3.renderers.extend([vline, vline2])
    # p.add_layout(vline)


for [driver_label, trace_colour, lap_time_label, lap_number_label], group_compare in group:

    p3.line(group_compare['x_new'], group_compare['curvature'], legend_label = driver_label + ' Lap - ' + str(lap_number_label) + ' = ' + str(round(lap_time_label, 2)), line_width = 1,line_color = trace_colour) # *2000+300



# make the legend interactive 
#p3.legend.click_policy="hide"

#p3.line('x_new','curvature', source = source)


# add callback to control 

button = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["Sector_1", "Sector_2","Sector_3"], active=0) #, callback = callback

button.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p3, source=source), code="""

            var radio_value = cb_obj.active;
            var data = source.data;  

            x = data['Lap Distance']
            x_new = data['x_new']

            gps_lat = data['GPS latitude']
            gps_lat_filtered = data['gps_lat_filtered']

            x_filter = data['callback_tag']
            y = data['curvature']

            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if(x_filter[i] == radio_value) {
                    x_new[i] = x[i];
                    gps_lat_filtered[i] = gps_lat[i];
                } else {
                    x_new[i] = undefined;
                    gps_lat_filtered[i] = undefined;
                }
            }
        source.change.emit();
        """)
```

but if i try and loop over the groupby so that i can have separate lines then the customJS callback no longer works as i have to remove the source = source line from the p.line():

when i assign the df only to columndatasource and then use this:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df_final)

p3.line('x_new','curvature', source = source)
```

then it works perfectly, but i want to be able to group the data and plot separate lines

can anyone please help me with the syntax as i am close to getting what i need, thanks